# Django SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed using Postfix on Centos

Tags: python, django, centos, sendmail, postfix-mta

I have installed Postfix on Centos 7 and have successfully configured it to send mail (tested with command line program MailX).

However, when trying to send mail through Django shell or my Django website I am getting:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 367, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

My mail configuration in settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Admin <admin@mywebsite.com>'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There should be more information in the Postfix log file (on Centos it's /var/log/maillog if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 1):

Maillog highlighted:

> fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms

Resolved with:

```
yum install cyrus-sasl-plain
```